# Is it possible to include multiple JavaScript libraries in an Ember.js add-on shim?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, shim, ember-cli-addons

If I want to create an add-on for **Ember.js**, let's call it **ember-awesome** for the purpose of this question, that is a wrapper around a library *awesome-lib.js* and its extensions. How do I create a shim around that library and any extensions I want to bundle with it?

Assume for a moment that `awesome-lib.js` can have plugins or extensions to its funcitonality, e.g. `awesome-ext-foo.js`, `awesome-ext-bar.js`, etc. What is the best way to write a shim for and add-on that provides awesome-lib, awesome-ext-foo, and awesome-ext-bar to the component?

I thought I might be able to define a single shim, e.g. `vendor/shims/awesome-lib-shim.js` as such:

```
// ember-awesome/vendor/shims/awesome-lib-shim.js
define("awesome-lib", [
  "awesome-lib",
  "awesome-ext-foo",
  "awesome-ext-bar"], function(awesomeLib, extFoo, extBar) {
  return {
    "default": awesomeLib,
    "foo": extFoo,
    "bar": extBar
  };
})
```

And use it in my `ember-awesome/index.js` as such:

```
// ember-awesome/index.js
module.exports = {
  name: "ember-awesome",

  included: function(app) {
    ...
    this.app.import("vendor/shims/awesome-lib-shim.js", {
      type: "vendor",
      exports: {
        "awesome-lib": ["default"],
        "awesome-ext-foo": ["foo"],
        "awesome-ext-bar": ["bar"],
      }
    });
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

This doesn't seem to work though. I can always create different shims, sure, but thought it would make the most sense to bundle like-components together in the same shim.

A good, real world, example of the type library and extension complexity I'm looking to write an add-on around is the [markdown-it](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/) and its [extensions](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it#syntax-extensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems like you need to understand a few concepts first.
Every call to `define` just defines [one modul](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#namedmodules).

The second argument is an *array of dependencies*. So lets look at your example:

```
define("awesome-lib", [
  "awesome-lib",
  "awesome-ext-foo",
  "awesome-ext-bar"], ...)
```

This actually defines an model called `awesome-lib` that depends on three modules: `awesome-lib`, `awesome-ext-foo`, `awesome-ext-bar`.

So this *can't* work. Especially it would mean that there are already three modules defined: `awesome-lib`, `awesome-ext-foo` and `awesome-ext-bar`. If however `awesome-lib` is already defined, why redefine it?

So generally you don't need a `vendor-shim` if something is already available as module. You use a vendor shim to make something global exported available as a module because you don't want to use the global everywhere, and maybe hope that in the future your dependency will be available as a module.

However, for this reason its absolutely possible to define multiple modules in one vendor shim with something like that:

```
define("awesome-lib", [], () => {
  return window.AwesomeLib;
})

define("awesome-ext-foo", ["awesome-lib"], awesomeLib => {
  return window.AwesomeLib.use(window.AwesomeExtFoo)
})
```

Next, the [definition of exports during app.import is not doing anything](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli.github.io/issues/84).

For your example however I don't see any reason to write an addon for that! You should install it from npm and then import it with [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify), That way it should also work for the extensions.

But if you want to write an addon to provide additional templates I also would rely on ember-browserify to install the dependency whenever possible.

Comment: I should have clarified in the example above was a library, and extensions to said library, that were not modularized in the sense of AMD, CommonJS, etc. Thanks for your answer.